# Twig if statement not including escaped code

Tags: html, if-statement, escaping, twig, symfony

I'm using Twig in Symfony3 and in my view I have an if statement. The html isn't rendered but the escaped twig does get rendered.

Here's my code:

```
{% if not private %}
    <h2>group</h2>
    <fieldset>
        {{ form_row(form.group) }}
    </fieldset>
 {% endif %}
```

So the `<h2>` isn't show, but the `{{ form_row(form.group) }}` gets rendered. How do I 'include' that escaped form part into that if statement?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
This is what actually gets rendered.

```
<div class="user_group">
        <div class="lbl"><label for="group">Group</label></div>
        <div class="vals"><input type="text" id="group" name="user[group]"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, that part of the form gets rendered, but the `<h2>` isn't shown because the if was false.

Comment: This awfully sounds like browser engine's work at hand. Can you open you `Firebug` / `DevTools` and see what has actually been included there?

Comment: I added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong. At the end of the page `form_end(form)` is called. And every part of the form that hasn't been called yet gets rendered there.

So I just need to maybe put that part of the form somewhere else or put it in a hidden input. I'll see.

**EDIT** Answer found!
When not mentioning a form element and you don't want it to be rendered when using `form_end(form)`, I just use `form_end(form, {'render_rest': false })`